# Custom Settings - Visibility Protected - Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, customsetting

I have a requirement to create a protected (visibility) custom setting which will be part of managed released package, now in the next release we need to make the visibility to public.

I know there are several scenarios where once some components are packaged you cannot update/delete the properties.

Q) If I make the visibility of a custom setting to Protected in v1.0 of a managed package, and in v1.1 make it public, does salesforce allow it?

Regards,

Comment: No. You will not be able to modify the visibility once it is packaged and released

Answer (score 7):

No. You will not be able to modify the visibility once it is packaged and released

Comment: In fact, you can't change the setting from the moment it's *created*. It's a done deal, forever.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to the Summer 15 release, you could not change the visibility of custom settings once they were created. But starting in Metadata API v. 34.0, you can change a custom setting from protected *to* public (but not the other way around) using the Metadata API, even after managed package release, unless you're in a patch organization. The user interface doesn't support doing this yet, though.